# Why my Gridview will disappear after clicking on page 2(Paging)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have 7 records in my database table which is called EntryTable. I set page limit to 5 records for each page. So page 1 will have 5 records, and page2 will have 2 records. But after I click Search All  and click page 2, the whole gridview disappear.

**After Searching for All**
[image]

**After clicking page 2**
[image]

```
public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            bindResultGridView();

        }

        string memName = (String)Session["UserName"];
        if (Session["Username"] != null && Session["Username"] != String.Empty)
        {
            //txtUserName.Text = "Welcome, " + memName + "!";


        }
    }

    protected void SearchBlog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {
            string invalid = txtSearch.Text;

            String SQL = null;

            if (invalid == "all")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable] WHERE AdminNumber LIKE @searchAdminNumber OR BlogType LIKE @searchBlogType OR Name LIKE @searchName";
            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchBlogType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchBlogType"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchName"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchAdminNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchAdminNumber"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdResult.DataSource = dt;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            lblError.Text = "";


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblError.Text = null;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Record not found";
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error!";
            //lblOrderError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }



    private void bindResultGridView()
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {
            string invalid = txtSearch.Text;

            String SQL = null;

            if (invalid == "all")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable] WHERE AdminNumber LIKE @searchAdminNumber OR BlogType LIKE @searchBlogType OR Name LIKE @searchName";
            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchBlogType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchBlogType"].Value = txtSearch.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchName"].Value = txtSearch.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchAdminNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchAdminNumber"].Value = txtSearch.Text;



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdResult.DataSource = dt;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            lblError.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    protected void grdResult_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Compare(e.CommandName, "Page", true) != 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/ResultDetails.aspx?cat=" + e.CommandArgument);
        }
    }


    protected void grdResult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int newPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdResult.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
        bindResultGridView();
    }
}
```

**EDITED**

**AFTER clicking on page 2**
[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        bindResultGridView();



    string memName = (String)Session["UserName"];
    if (Session["Username"] != null && Session["Username"] != String.Empty)
    {
        //txtUserName.Text = "Welcome, " + memName + "!";


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Maybe the `grdResult_PageIndexChanging` event doesn't fire

So create a break point on

```
    int newPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

or on this line

```
    grdResult.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
```

If this event doesn't run, maybe your result grid has not been attached this event. Please try to reattach it again and I think, chances will work.

EDITS:

finally edit with this

```
    else if (invalid == "") { 
     SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]"; 
    }
```

Comment: What about grdResult_PageIndexChanging? There is bindResultGridView(); in it

Comment: I removed if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
      

    } Still the same thing @Bellash

Comment: Erm sorry I think i figure out something, actually in this question that I asked, i actually didn't key in All and search it. I key in nothing and search it and after going page 2, the gridview will disappear. But if I type All and click search, and click page 2, it will display the neccessary records. How to solved the problem of typeing in nothing without the gridview to disappear when clicking page 2? @Bellash

Comment: Did it with this. Thanks anyway. Do you want to put this as answer so I can tick?          else if (invalid == "")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }

Comment: edited my answer. Thank your for your participation @Jordjmax